# Why does this come up as non-object?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am trying to create a really simple database connection class in PHP, but I ran into a bit of problem.

First off, here's the code I wrote:

```
class db {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=main', 'root', '');
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to call `$db` from another class that extends my database class, I get an error like this one:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in class.php

I call the database link in the other class like the following example:

```
class example extends db {  

    public function challenge_exists($challenge) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE challenge = :challenge');
        $query->bindParam(':challenge', $challenge, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }           
    }   
}
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong and would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this work.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Oops, you're right.

Comment: 1. How do you call `$db` 2. did you test to make sure the connection was successful? 3. In your child class did you call the parent constructor?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I call the $db in the other class as $this->db because I have extended it. I am certain the connection must be successful as I have tested it while trying to tackle the problem.

Comment: Post the constructor of child class.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the question, if there is a `__construct()` method in the child class then you need to call the `__construct()` of the parent class explicitly, or else it is not executed and `$db` is never instantiated.  Though you don't show the child constructor in your example code it is safe to assume that there is one based on the behavior, so:

```
class example extends db {

    public function __construct() {    
        parent::__construct();
        //more stuff   
    }
}
```

If you don't need a constructor in the child class then remove it and the parent constructor will be called when you instantiate an object of the child class.

As for the design, this is bad and you should consider one database object and inject that into objects that need it or similar approach:

```
class example {

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

$db = new db();              // do this once
$example = new example($db); // inject when needed
```

Answer (score -1):

You should never extend an applications class from a database class in the first place.

User is not a database. It's a user. They have nothing in common. Database have to be used as a service by a user, not being a parent.

Not to mention that creating a hundred connections from the same script is a very bad idea.

Regarding the "accepted" answer, it's just wrong. As long as there is no constructor in the child class defined (like in the OP), then parent counstructor is used. Welcome to Stack Overfraud.

Comment: I've edited, but not wrong.  Whether it was shown or not, obviously they had a constructor in the child class.